# How to execute local python scripts in jenkins through maven

Tags: python, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to Jenkins, And need to execute some python scripts stored in my local machine through maven in Jenkins. Could some one guide me about this.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974445/maven-exec-plugin-executing-a-python-script ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a python script through maven you don't have to worry about Jenkins. Because from Jenkins you will be executing maven commands and maven will take care of executing the Python script. For this you can use something like the [maven exec plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html).  But if you want to execute a python command before executing the maven command you can use a shell executor for this. Following is a sample pipeline for this.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Sample') {
            steps {
                script {
                    git branch: 'master'
                        url: 'git@github.com:ycr/sample.git'
                   }
                    sh """
                        python hello.py // Execute python
                        mvn clean install // Execute maven
                    """
            }
        }
    }
}
```